# TestNG Commandline throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, testng

I have a library of TestNG tests I have created in Eclipse. I am trying to set a separate machine up to run them from a cron job. The first step (in my mind) is to get them running from the command line on that computer. I'm pretty new to TestNG, and this is my first attempt at running from command line (configuration problems are definitely a potential).

Currently, I am receiving a NullPointer Exception when I run the TestSuite. There are three tests being run.

```
$ java -Xmx1024m -ea -Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII -classpath ./*:/usr/share/java/*:lib/*:lib/google/guice/* org.testng.TestNG  -d . ./smoke.xml
[Parser] Running:
  /home/qabot/testing/autotest/smoke.xml


===============================================
SystemHealth
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.PackageUtils.findClassesInDirPackage(PackageUtils.java:183)
    at org.testng.internal.PackageUtils.findClassesInDirPackage(PackageUtils.java:185)
    at org.testng.internal.PackageUtils.findClassesInDirPackage(PackageUtils.java:185)
    at org.testng.internal.PackageUtils.findClassesInPackage(PackageUtils.java:56)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlPackage.initializeXmlClasses(XmlPackage.java:78)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlPackage.getXmlClasses(XmlPackage.java:69)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:189)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:151)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:488)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:250)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:204)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createAndRunSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:915)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:879)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:787)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:952)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:925)
```

*Environment:*

```
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
java version "1.7.0_21"
testng-jdk15-5.11.jar
```